# Toolbar menu causes my application to crash when opened

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I'm having trouble with the menu in my toolbar. The project builds but when the drop down menu is pressed in the top corner,the application crashes. At first i thought it may have been a problem inflating the menu itself but i can't locate the line that is causing this error.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CircleImageView usrImg;
    TextView usrName;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference ref;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //<-------TOOLBAR LAYOUT----------->
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }

    //MENU CONTROLS
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.signOut:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/brLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgProfile"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtProfile"
                android:text="USERNAME"
                android:textColor="#FEFCFB"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:title="Messages"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/signOut"
        android:title="Sign Out"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

ERROR:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mseabraham.finalyearapp, PID: 26662
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:477)
        at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3539)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:924)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:869)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:94)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:161)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:174)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:208)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:797)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Check your XML file line number 51 or upload your file here.

Comment: @AjayThakur which xml file? because the xml file for main activity doesn't have a line 51 but i've uploaded anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the line of code given below. Provide any custom theme or any other theme and if you don't want any theme you can also delete **popupTheme** it will work fine

```
 app:popupTheme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"
```

Comment: Yea that works now! Do you know what other popupThemes are available for a toolbar dropdown menu then?

Comment: yea, of course, please check this link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QUBiHkT81A here you will find how to make a custom theme. Thank you